# What are reasons to prefer waxed canvas vs. nylon bags?

Tags: gear, canvas

I have been reading some "make your own gear" forums, and making waxed canvas bags seems to be a popular craft.

I recently did a little research into ripstop nylon (for another SE, [here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/2437/robust-fabric-for-making-a-bag-for-a-3d-printer/2438)), and it seems to have the same desirable qualities as waxed canvas - tough, strong, waterproof. However, nylon weighs a lot less, so I'd think it would be preferred over waxed canvas for serious hikers and backpackers.

My guess is that for DIY'ers it's mostly aesthetics - waxed canvas bags usually look pretty cool compared to a nylon sack. But I've never used a waxed canvas bag myself, so I'm curious if there are other advantages.

What are some reasons you might prefer a waxed canvas bag over a nylon bag?

Comment: It is a tough, nice looking, renewable and ecological product. For backpacking I would never consider it, though.

Comment: also, ripstop nylon comes in all shapes and sizes, depending on what you want, and with a lot of different coatings for waterproofing

Answer (score 7):

Canvass is:

- More expensive
- Heavier
- Easier to repair
- Easier to waterproof
- More rugged
- Once it gets mildewed, it's done forever

Nylon is:

- Cheaper
- Lighter
- Harder to repair
- Harder to waterproof
- Less rugged; carry only soft/dull things; don't scrape the ground
- Mildewed?  No problem.  Wash with Chlorox, then you're good to go
- More colorful options

Your answer, therefore, depends on your needs and preferences.

Comment: why would nylon be harder to repair? Also, the level of ruggedness varies a lot. 1000D cordura is not the same as 10D sylnylon, Dyneema grid in fabrics also changes a lot the strength of the material, and multi-layers fabrics have other properties (like X-Pac fabrics).

Comment: Nylon is insanely difficult to work with when creating tear-resistant attachments and seams.  Too much stitching, and you essentially cut a line into the fabric; too little, and stitching is weak.  If you repair a hole or tear, you're limited to sewing or gluing patches, but you incur a similar risk when sewing, and with gluing, it can work, but not all glues work with all nylon fabric.

Comment: Also, nylon has a tendency to rip.  So, if I had a nylon tent or tarp, it would not withstand strong winds, particularly in colder weather - especially when there is snow.  I'll trust canvass any day, besides the benefit of it being somewhat warmer, even if not able to stop wind as well.  As to siliconized nylon, it can be durable, but the ultra lights used by backpackers is too brittle; I would never use it in rugged conditions.

Comment: @Wigwam, thanks for the insights here! I am little confused by your comment on ripping though, isn't ripstop nylon was specifically made to avoid that?

Comment: @Wigwam we are typically talking about silicone- or PU-coated nylons. On those, sil- or PU-based sealant work well as glue. For attachment points, reinforcements are easy to add. Ripstop goes a long way in limiting the risks of tear. And if you are actually going to compare how fabrics fare in strong winds, compare equivalent weights. A basic 10oz canvas will not work any better than a 10oz nylon.

Comment: @njzk2 - I disagree about any simplicity to fix or reinforce nylon.  Perhaps, if one has access to a facility who has the expertise and equipment, that would be one thing.  The average hiker does not have these resources.  Canvass does require heavier needles and either fingers of steel or a tough sewing machine.  But, the OP asked about DIY, and one would have to have knowledge of the different kinds of nylon and canvass material, and most just don't.

Having said that, I'd love to see a point-and-click website where one can design their own bag or backpack, and include details such as...

Comment: @njzk2 ... where zippers, pockets, handles, reinforcement points, and other attachments can go, and include the capability to define a fabric to use.  In this case, I might still decide to design a backpack out of canvass, or a compression bag or stuff sack out of nylon, a dutch oven cover out of canvass, and a tarp out of nylon.  Additionally, I would like a belt-held tool carrier out of canvass, a silverware protector out of canvass (to protect the nylon bag I'd put it in), and a nylon backpacking tarp.

Comment: @njzk2 - Lightweight, durability, ruggedness, ease of repair, color, breatheability - they all go into considering one material vs another.  I might mention that much of my military bivouac materials once made out of canvass (duffel bag, back pack, ammunitition cases, first aid kits, etc) are now made out of nylon material that is just as thick as canvass.  But most civilians don't yet have access to this kind of material, so canvass rules for the moment.

Comment: @whrrgarbl - yes, ripstop is great for that.  But working the material is not easy and requires skill and resources.  If designing bags and backpacks, much depends on use.  For back country hiking, light weight is important; I might go with nylon.  For day trips, canvass is better: such will be taken on and off, tossed here and there; I prefer canvass and leather for things like this.